# Calculation of $\int\frac{x^2 \left(\sin 2x - \cos 2x\right)}{\left(1+\sin 2x\right)\cos^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus

Calculation of $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^2 \left(\sin 2x - \cos 2x\right)}{\left(1+\sin 2x\right)\cos^2 x}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ We can write the given Integral as $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^2 \left\{(1+\sin 2x)-(1+\cos 2x)\right\}}{(1+\sin 2x)\cos^2 x}dx$

$\displaystyle  = \int\frac{x^2}{\cos^2 x}dx - \int \frac{2x^2}{1+\sin 2x}dx$

$\displaystyle  = \int x^2 \sec^2 xdx - \int\frac{x^2}{\cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}dx$

$\displaystyle = \int x^2 \sec^2 xdx - \int x^2 \sec^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)dx$

Now I did not understand how can i solve that

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts with $x^2$ as the first term

Comment: You may use Integration by Parts.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use integration by parts. This is:

$\displaystyle \int u dv = uv - \int vdu$

For your problem it's a bit tedious, but doable... Make things like x^2 u because it will become a constant eventually.

Answer (score 1):

My hint

$$\int x^2d(\tan x)+\int x^2d(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x))=x^2(\tan x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x))-2\int x(\tan x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x))dx$$

$$\int x(\tan x+\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x))dx=\int \frac{x}{\cos x(\sin x+\cos x)}dx$$

This is the [result.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20x%28tan%20x%2btan%28%5Cpi/4-x%29%29)